# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In my Django Project `market` I created an app called `main`. In `main` I created `urls.py`

`main/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
import views
url_patterns = [
    path('home/', views.homepage, name='home'),

]
```

`main/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1> Hello World </h1>" )
```

`market/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls'))
]
```

But when I try to run:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\worksapce\jimDjango\market\market\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('main.urls'))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\worksapce\jimDjango\market\main\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'
```

Why won't this run?

Edit:
I also tried replacing `import views` in `main/urls.py` with `from market.main import views`. Doesn't help.

Comment: Your code does not match the error message. Your code doesn't have any mention of `market.main`, it just says `import views`.

Comment: @MattDMo That was from experimenting with the import to see if it changes anything. I fixed it so it matches.

Comment: `from . import views`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two problems with what I did:

1. I didn't import `views.py` correctly. I should've used `from . import views` instead of `import views` in `main/urls.py`. (Thanks to user @bdbd)
2. In `main/urls.py` I wrote `url_patterns` instead of `urlpatterns`